# CSS code rendering different result in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, embedded-ruby

I am currently learning Ruby on Rails by following Micheal Hartl's tutorial to create a twitter clone.

I was working on the CSS code for the front page. But for some weird reason, It is rendering a different view for both Firefox and Chrome.

I have added screenshots. The navigation bar in the upper right page ( consisting of Home, Help and Sign In) seems to disappear in Firefox.

I have tried tinkering around with the code, but I just can't seem to get the logo and the navigation bar to get aligned in Firefox, like they are aligned in Chrome.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

Here is the CSS code:

```
.container{

width: 710px;
padding-left:30px;
}

body{

background: #cff;
padding-left:30px;
margin:1em;
}

header{
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-left: 20px;


}

header img {
padding: 1em;
background: #fff;
position: relative;
margin-left:-1.1em;
}

section{
 margin-top:1em;
 font-size:120%;
 padding:20px;
 background: #fff;
 }

 section h1{
 font-size:200%;
 }


 a{
 color: #09c  ;
 text-decoration:none;
 }

 a:hover{
 color: #069;
 text-decoration:underline;
 font-weight:bold;
 }

 a:visited{
 color:#069;
 }

 nav{

 float:right;
 background: white;
 padding: 0 0.7em;
white-space:nowrap;
margin-top: -5.4em;
margin-left:-0.4em;


 }

 nav ul{

 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

 nav ul li{

 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:0.2em 0;
 }

 nav ul li a {

 padding: 0 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
 }

 nav ul li a:visited{
 color: #09c;
 }

 nav ul li a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
 }


 a.signup {

 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 width: 190px;
 color:#fff;
 background: #006400;
 font-size:150%;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:20px;
 }

 .round{

 border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:10px;
 }

 footer {

 text-align: center;
 width:800px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:100px;
 } 

 footer nav{

 float:none;
 }
```

The image and the Navigations are defined in the header.html.erb page. The code of that page is:

```
<header>
      <%= link_to logo,root_path %>
     <nav class = "round">


      <ul>

       <li> <%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
       <li> <%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
       <li> <%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
      </ul> 
      </nav>
</header>
```

Here is the source code generated by Chrome:

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <header>
      <a href="/"><img alt="Sample app" class="round" src="/assets/logo.png" /></a>
     <nav class = "round">


      <ul>

       <li> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
       <li> <a href="/help">Help</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      </ul> 
      </nav>
</header>
    <section class ="round">

<h1>KHEMS</h1>
<p>
This is the home page for Khems - A Micro blogging App. It is similar to Twitter.
</p>

<a href="#" class="signup round">Sign up now!</a>


     </section>
     <footer>
 <nav class = "round">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li> <a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://github.com/piy9/Twitter_clone" target="_blank">Git Repo</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://railstutorial.org" target="_blank">Rails Tutorial</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</footer>

     </div> 
</body>
```

Source code generated by Firefox:

```
 <body>
   <div class="container">
    <header>
      <a href="/"><img alt="Sample app" class="round" src="/assets/logo.png" /></a>
     <nav class = "round">


      <ul>

       <li> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
       <li> <a href="/help">Help</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      </ul> 
      </nav>
</header>
    <section class ="round">

<h1>KHEMS</h1>
<p>
This is the home page for Khems - A Micro blogging App. It is similar to Twitter.
</p>

<a href="#" class="signup round">Sign up now!</a>


     </section>
     <footer>
 <nav class = "round">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li> <a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://github.com/piy9/Twitter_clone" target="_blank">Git Repo</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://railstutorial.org" target="_blank">Rails Tutorial</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</footer>

     </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: `margin-top: -5.4em;` seems to be a problem in your `nav` CSS definition. Can you share your whole HTML markup? With layout problems it's best to show **all** HTML and CSS

Comment: @zgood : Removing the `margin-top` stub from `nav` does indeed correct the problem for Firefox, but again messes up the view in Chrome. 
There are no html files, only embedded html ruby files - Applications, header and footer. The applications files contains ruby partials pointing to the header and footers. I have shared the headers file. There seems to be no problem with the footers.

Comment: I suspect there maybe something fishy with the DOM. Can you run it locally in either FireFox or Chrome, then right click and view source to see the rendered DOM and copy and paste that code here (everything between the `<body>` tags)?

Comment: They both look like your FireFox example for me in both FireFox and Chrome. What version of Chrome are you using? Do you have any other styles or stylesheets used?

Comment: No I don't have any other stylesheets. I am using the latest version of Chrome viz Chrome v 31.0.1650.63m

Comment: Ok I'm on Chrome Version 32.0.1700.72 m. But anyways see if my below answer helps any.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that you have this CSS definition:

```
nav {
    float: right;
    background: white;
    padding: 0 0.7em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: -5.4em;
    margin-left: -0.4em;
}
```

Which is being applied to **BOTH** your `nav` in your `<header>` and in your `<footer>`. I would remove `margin-top: -5.4em;` completely and then change this CSS definition:

```
footer {
   text-align: center;
   width: 800px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

by updating `margin-top: 100px;` to something like `margin-top: 20px;` and see if you have any better luck.